# extract substring with SED

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I have the next strings:
 for example:

```
     input1 = abc-def-ghi-jkl

     input2 = mno-pqr-stu-vwy
```

I want extract the first word between "-"

for the fisrt string I want to get: **def**

if the input is the second string, I want to get: **pqr**

**I want to use the command SED**, Could you help me please?

Comment: Why sed? This is a job for grep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use `sed`, you can choose between solutions like

```
# Double processing
echo "$input1" | sed 's/[^-]*-//;s/-.*//'
# Normal approach
echo "$input1" | sed -r 's/^[^-]*-([^-]*)|-.*)/\1/g'
# Funny alternative
echo "$input1" | sed -r 's/(^[^-]*-|-.*)//g'
```

The obvious "external" tool would be `cut`. You can also look at a Bash builtin solution like

```
[[ ${input1} =~ ([^-]*)-([^-]*) ]] && printf %s "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sed 's,^[^-]*-\([^-]*\).*,\1,' file
```

The string after the first `-` will be captured up to the second `-` and the rest will be matched, then the matched line will be replaced with the group text.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`:

```
var='input1 = abc-def-ghi-jkl'
var=${var#*-}      # remove shortest prefix `*-`, this removes `input1 = abc-`
echo "${var%%-*}"  # remove longest suffix `-*`, this removes `-ghi-jkl`
```

---

Or with `awk`:

```
awk -F'-' '{print $2}' <<<'input1 = abc-def-ghi-jkl'
```

Use `-` as input field separator and print the second field.

---

Or with `cut`:

```
cut -d'-' -f2 <<<'input1 = abc-def-ghi-jkl'
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` solution (in my opinion this is the most natural approach, as you are only trying to find matches to a regular expression - you are not looking to **edit** anything, so there should be no need for the more advanced command `sed`)

```
grep -oP '^[^-]*-\K[^-]*(?=-)' << EOF
> abc-qrs-bobo-the-clown
> 123-45-6789
> blah-blah-blah
> no dashes here
> mahi-mahi
> EOF
```

**Output**

```
qrs
45
blah
```

**Explanation**

Look at the inputs first, included here for completeness as a **heredoc** (more likely you would name your file as the last argument to `grep`.) The solution requires at least two dashes to be present in the string; in particular, for `mahi-mahi` it will find no match. If you want to find the second `mahi` as a match, you can remove the lookahead assertion at the end of the regular expression (see below).

The regular expression does this. First note the command options: `-o` to return only the matched substring, not the entire line; and `-P` to use Perl extensions. Then, the regular expression: start from the beginning of the line (`^`); look for zero or more non-dash characters followed by dash, and then (`\K`) *discard* this part of the required match from the substrings found to match the pattern. Then look for zero or more non-dash characters again - this will be returned by the command. Finally, require a dash following this pattern, but do not include it in the match. This is done with a *lookahead* (marked by `(?= ... )`).